# Write to a NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, xml, namevaluecollection

I am trying to implement a simple construct where I first clear the NameValueCollection and the write new values to it. However at the moment I can't because it is read only. Is there a way to make it not read only or a walk around?
My Code:

```
NameValueCollection DataDictionary = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataDictionary") as NameValueCollection;
            DataDictionary.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount; i++)
            {
                var T = tableLayoutPanel2.GetControlFromPosition(1, i);
                var T2 = tableLayoutPanel2.GetControlFromPosition(3, i);
                string key = T.Text;
                string value = T2.Text;
                DataDictionary.Add(key, value);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy it in a [new `NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s711zk3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var writableCollection = new NameValueCollection(DataDictionary);
writableCollection.Add(...);
```

Comment: Yes this would work but I'm trying to rewrite back to the XML file so how could I do this with the new `writableCollection`?

Comment: [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306130/how-do-i-save-custom-configuration-sections-during-runtime). If you really must you can try using Xml library functions, but configuration sections apart from appSettings are designed to be read-only.